# Objective-C and Cocoa : crash when calling a class function without entering the function

Tags: objective-c, crash, debugging, function-call

I have a class function (declared and implemented) in a class MyUtils.
When I call this function my app crashes. In the debugger I have a breakpoint on the first action of the "theFunction" function. And this breakpoint is never reached.

Here is the code :

```
// =================================================================================================
// MyUtils.m
// =================================================================================================
+ (NSString*) changeDateFormat_fromFormat:(NSString*)sourceFormat sourceDateString:(NSString*)sourceDateString destFormat:(NSString*)destFormat {
    if (sourceDateString == nil) return (nil); **<-- breakpoint here**

    NSDate* aDate = [NSDate dateFromString:sourceFormat theDateString:sourceDateString];
    return ([aDate stringValueWithFormat:destFormat]);
}

// ===================================================================
// MyUtils.h
// ===================================================================
@interface MyUtils
+ (NSString*) changeDateFormat_fromFormat:(NSString*)sourceFormat sourceDateString:(NSString*)sourceDateString destFormat:(NSString*)destFormat;
+ (void) simpleAlert_ok:(NSString*)alertTitle message:(NSString*)alertMessage;

@end


// ===================================================================
// Elsewhere.m
// ===================================================================
- (void) aFunction:(SomeClass*)someParam {
    SomeOtherClass* val = nil;
    NSString* intitule = nil;


    intitule = [MyUtils changeDateFormat_fromFormat:@"yyyyMMdd" sourceDateString:@"toto" destFormat:@"EEEE dd MMMM yyyy"]; **<-- crash here**
```

The console says :

```
2011-01-03 02:05:07.188 Learning Project[1667:207] *** NSInvocation: warning: object 0xe340 of class 'MyUtils' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
2011-01-03 02:05:07.188 Learning Project[1667:207] *** NSInvocation: warning: object 0xe340 of class 'MyUtils' does not implement doesNotRecognizeSelector: -- abort
```

If I replace the call by `NSString *item = @"youyou";` then everything is ok.

Forcing a retain on aPreviousNSString before the call does not change anything.
Do you have an idea of what is happening ?

Comment: Can we see more code? I'm guessing that `MyUtils` is a singleton. Is that correct?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be your actual code. In creating a mock example, you might have missed crucial aspects of the real code that's crashing. Please show us what you're actually using.

Comment: @Moshe No, then it'd be `[[MyUtils sharedUtils] ...]`

Comment: @JacobRelkin - True, but the concept sounds like it would be a singleton utility class. Also, remember, that the naming convention is not required - it could be whatever he wants it to be.

Comment: What is the console output? What is the stacktrace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declared `MyUtils` without a superclass, so the runtime is complaining that it doesn't implement certain basic behaviors (rightfully so). You probably meant to inherit from `NSObject`:

```
@interface MyUtils : NSObject {
}

+ (NSString*) changeDateFormat_fromFormat:(NSString*)sourceFormat sourceDateString:(NSString*)sourceDateString destFormat:(NSString*)destFormat;
+ (void) simpleAlert_ok:(NSString*)alertTitle message:(NSString*)alertMessage;
@end
```

Comment: That's it... I didn't though this was the cause of the error. Any class must at least inherit NSObject... That's written in my head :-)  But... Can someone explain me why if I wait into the debugger before calling the function, sometimes it works fine without the superclass ?

Answer (score 3):

You do not have a superclass declared on your MyUtils class. To fix it, just change `@interface MyUtils` to `@interface MyUtils : NSObject`. If you do not declare a superclass, you have to provide all of the required methods yourself.

Comment: ok, but why if I wait into the debugger before calling the function, sometimes it works fine without the superclass ?

Comment: That's interesting. I would guess that when you wait, the runtime looks through the class directly instead of calling methodSignatureForSelector: and doesNotRespondToSelector:, but I have no idea why it would do that.

Answer (score 1):

Your class needs to be of some object type for it to be compilable. The base object in Objective-C for iOS is NSObject, all classes inherit from it.

You want to change the line that says:

`@interface MyUtils`

to this:

```
@interface MyUtils : NSObject { 


}

  + (NSString *) ... ... ...
```

For more information on NSObject, see the [NSObject Class reference in the Apple Developer Library](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: ok, but why if I wait into the debugger before calling the function, sometimes it works fine without the superclass ?

Comment: I suggest cleaning your project (Command+Shift+K) and then rebuilding it. See what happens.